# Undesired FrameLayout Stretch to Wrap All Children's Heights (Instead of Respecting Just One Child's Height)

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, android-xml, android-framelayout

Basically, I am using a popular tactic to center a background image for a `LinearLayout` by wrapping it in a `FrameLayout` and adding an ImageView that uses `fill_parent` before the `LinearLayout`. However, when I add a `ScrollView` in the game, everything changes.

The issues is that the image is quite large vertically and the `ScrollView` respects the height of both the `ImageView` and the `LinearLayout` due to the `wrap_content` height attribute. This causes an undesired blank space below the LinearLayout when the image is vertically larger than it.

How do I make the `FrameLayout`'s height stretch only to the child LinearLayout's height? If possible, without mangling with its sizes programmatically on run-time/draw-time.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/cash_bg" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- My main views are here -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and gone nuts searching for an answer. I think this is an Android bug. What I have done is to include the FrameLayout into a LinearLayout to be able to force "fill_parent" on FrameLayout's height, which increases the complexity, but solves the problem. Did not find any other (better) solution. 
Try this:

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true" >
  <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/cash_bg" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- My main views are here -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```